blank page after splash screen, but if i reload, it works
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lie8TxcOFIA&ab_channel=taro
This problem only popped up recently, I just changed my splash screen to add an image via LaunchScreen.storyboard in XCode, and now it doesn't work??
I am connected to Metro.
The same thing happens in Simulator.
Timeline:
stuck on black screen
2024-04-22 00:43:43.684373+0800 Safeplate[4386:92460] [native] Running application Safeplate ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2024-04-22 00:43:43.965759+0800 Safeplate[4386:92658] Metal API Validation Enabled
2024-04-22 00:43:44.699751+0800 Safeplate[4386:92658] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C5:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2024-04-22 00:43:44.700717+0800 Safeplate[4386:92657] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C5] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2024-04-22 00:43:44.700776+0800 Safeplate[4386:92657] TCP Conn 0x282680a50 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2024-04-22 00:43:44.937868+0800 Safeplate[4386:92666] [native] Unbalanced calls start/end for tag 19
2024-04-22 00:43:44.942487+0800 Safeplate[4386:92666] [javascript] Running "Safeplate" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}
2024-04-22 00:43:45.525195+0800 Safeplate[4386:92658] [native] Error setting property 'height' of RCTView with tag #63: (ADVICE) "13px" is not a valid dimension. Dimensions must be a number, "auto", or a string suffixed with "%".
2024-04-22 00:43:45.584860+0800 Safeplate[4386:92666] [javascript] (ADVICE) "13px" is not a valid dimension. Dimensions must be a number, "auto", or a string suffixed with "%".

reload -> unstuck
2024-04-22 00:44:14.663705+0800 Safeplate[4386:92672] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C7:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2024-04-22 00:44:14.664557+0800 Safeplate[4386:92657] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C7] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2024-04-22 00:44:14.665158+0800 Safeplate[4386:92657] TCP Conn 0x2826854a0 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2024-04-22 00:44:16.473199+0800 Safeplate[4386:92460] [native] Invalidating <RCTCxxBridge: 0x10490e440> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x283ab6450>, executor: (null))
2024-04-22 00:44:17.654538+0800 Safeplate[4386:92672] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C10:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2024-04-22 00:44:17.655616+0800 Safeplate[4386:92794] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C10] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2024-04-22 00:44:17.655682+0800 Safeplate[4386:92794] TCP Conn 0x2826804d0 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2024-04-22 00:44:17.834692+0800 Safeplate[4386:92790] [native] Unbalanced calls start/end for tag 19
2024-04-22 00:44:17.835831+0800 Safeplate[4386:92460] [native] Running application Safeplate ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 11;
})
2024-04-22 00:44:17.857498+0800 Safeplate[4386:92790] [javascript] Running "Safeplate" with {"rootTag":11,"initialProps":{}}
2024-04-22 00:44:18.303539+0800 Safeplate[4386:92672] [native] Error setting property 'height' of RCTView with tag #43: (ADVICE) "13px" is not a valid dimension. Dimensions must be a number, "auto", or a string suffixed with "%".

